# Jump to memory in GDB causes SIGSEGV

Tags: assembly, gdb, code-injection

I am trying to inject code into a running process using GDB and am getting a SIGSEGV everytime I attempt to run my code. I am on ubuntu (Oneiric). I export the code to an environment variable using a python script to print them out, then from within gdb, find the desired code with something like `x/50s *((char**)environ)`, and then pick a better address to examine instructions from.

So, when I do `x/30i *(addressOfCode)`, the assembly instructions there are an EXACT match with the ones I want to run. So, if I insert a breakpoint at the starting point of my code, jump there, and stepi, I get a segfault. Moreover, if I choose a place in memory and insert some NOPs, break at one of them, jump to it, and stepi, I also get a segfault.

How can I avoid this? Am I segfaulting just because I am jumping out of the designated memory for the process? What options are there for me to get around this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Am I segfaulting just because I am jumping out of the designated memory for the process?

I can't tell what above statement means. There is no such thing as "designated memory for process".

Most likely, you are getting `SIGSEGV` because you don't have executable stack (and environment variables on Linux and many other UNIX variants are passed on the stack).

If you are on Linux, try linking with `gcc main.c ... -Wl,-z,execstack`. If that makes your code injection work, then non-executable stack is indeed your problem.